# Нет доступа через Wi-fi на локальный сайт

Tags: ubuntu, сеть, virtualbox

На виртуальном сервере(VirtualBox) есть сайт. Ноутбук находится в WI-FI сети. Как сделать, что-бы все кто находится в этой сети, могли заходить на этот сайт.

IP компа - 192.168.0.106

IP VirtualBox - 192.168.100.1

eth0 - 192.168.100.100

настройка

```
sites-enabled/default 
 server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    location / {
        root /var/www;
        index index.html index.php;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_bridged

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой вариант - закинуть всё в одно адресное пространство. В настройках сети виртуалбокса сделай "сетевой мост".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: http://printscreen.ninja/s/49FM если нет eth0 в спсике

Comment: @Abylkhair, ну раз ноут общается со всеми через вайфай, то вот с ним мост и делай.